# LEFT JOIN select latest row from the left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, mysql-5.6

I have a company database that has all its details within it. It also has a separate table where credit ratings are stored.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address2` text NOT NULL,
  `address3` text NOT NULL,
  `phone` text NOT NULL,
  `contacts` text NOT NULL,
  `islive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `qt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
  `pt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `creditrating`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `creditrating` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `arating` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `thedate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `address`, `address2`, `address3`, `phone`, `contacts`, `islive`, `qt`, `pt`) VALUES
(190, 'Test Company', 'test@test.com', 'Testing Client 1\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 1\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 1\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', '65165156', 'test name', 1, 30, 30),
(191, 'Test Company 2', 'test2@test2.com', 'Testing Client 2\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 2\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 2\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', '65165156', 'test name 2', 1, 30, 30);

INSERT INTO `creditrating` (`id`, `cid`, `rating`, `arating`, `type`, `thedate`) VALUES
(3, 190, 684, 'da774', 1, '2021-03-30 15:08:52'),
(6, 190, 222, 'DD222', 1, '2021-03-30 17:46:22');
```

I am trying to only retrieve the company details and only the latest row on the credit rating table.

The SQL I have got closest to getting this to work is (Mysql 5.6):

```
SELECT c.id
     , AES_DECRYPT(c.name, 'co1') as name
     , AES_DECRYPT(c.phone, 'co3') as phone
     , c.islive
     , r.rating 
  FROM company c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN creditrating r 
    ON (SELECT r.thedate FROM creditrating WHERE c.id=r.cid ORDER BY r.thedate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

[DB FIDDLE HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t3ttuQGcMZizEmqmjoKUnu/0)

At the moment it is bringing back 2 rows of the same company instead of just 1.

Thank you in advance for any pointers you guys can through my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prior versions don't have window functions but you can switch to user defined variables

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`;
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
>   `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
>   `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `address2` text NOT NULL,
>   `address3` text NOT NULL,
>   `phone` text NOT NULL,
>   `contacts` text NOT NULL,
>   `islive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
>   `qt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
>   `pt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `creditrating`;
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `creditrating` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `arating` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
>   `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
>   `thedate` datetime NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> INSERT INTO `company` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `address`, `address2`, `address3`, `phone`, `contacts`, `islive`, `qt`, `pt`) VALUES
> (190, 'Test Company', 'test@test.com', 'Testing Client 1\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 1\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 1\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', '65165156', 'test name', 1, 30, 30),
> (191, 'Test Company 2', 'test2@test2.com', 'Testing Client 2\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 2\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', 'Testing Client 2\r\nsdfsdfsdf\r\nsdfsdfsdf', '65165156', 'test name 2', 1, 30, 30);
>
> INSERT INTO `creditrating` (`id`, `cid`, `rating`, `arating`, `type`, `thedate`) VALUES
> (3, 190, 684, 'da774', 1, '2021-03-30 15:08:52'),
> (6, 190, 222, 'DD222', 1, '2021-03-30 17:46:22');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     id, name, phone, islive, rating, `thedate`
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         name,
>             phone,
>             islive,
>             rating,
>             `thedate`,
>             IF(id = @id, @rnk:=@rnk + 1, @rnk:=1) AS rnk,
>             @id:=id AS id
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         c.id,
>             AES_DECRYPT(c.name, 'co1') AS name,
>             AES_DECRYPT(c.phone, 'co3') AS phone,
>             c.islive,
>             r.rating,
>             `thedate`
>     FROM
>         company c
>     LEFT JOIN creditrating r ON c.id = r.cid) t1, (SELECT @id:=- 1, @rnk:=0) t2
>     ORDER BY id , `thedate` DESC) t3
> WHERE
>     rnk = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | name | phone | islive | rating | thedate            
> --: | :--- | :---- | -----: | -----: | :------------------
> 190 | null | null  |      1 |    222 | 2021-03-30 17:46:22
> 191 | null | null  |      1 |   null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1276daf2397fc7a09e6dafe109d6be77)*

Comment: Thank you @nbk I have managed to get this far using something a different query, but your query has the same issue as mine, it is not bringing back r.thedate DESC.

Comment: @Robert see changed answer

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can I ask what you changed to get that to work?

Comment: the data are false sorted in the prior approaches, also i rewirote the join as with amn index on id this gets faster, that your approach

Comment: This is not correct; it is not guaranteed to work.  The MySQL documentation specifically warns against assigning a variable in one expression and then using it in another in the same `select`.  The order of evaluation of expressions is not guaranteed.

Comment: this works since years in mysql 5,5 5.6 band 5.7 that is a fact maradb doesn't keep the order at least not when you using a trick.

Comment: @Robert & nbk Reading & writing the same user variable in the same select statement has always had undefined behaviour. (And is deprecated in 8.0.) (Past observations & personal theories justify nothing.) Order by without top/limit not at the outermost level has no defined effect. (Tables have no order, result sets have order.)

Comment: It works but I am a little worried because of the fact it was deprecated in 8.0. Is it just simply better to run the 2nd query after the initial query rather than hack it like this?

Comment: this is no hack, this was made so for years and you will find some amount of posts from me, that do this. In future this still works for now, but mysql has announced that the behaviour could change, so when you migrate, you will have to adept some things, but he break from 5.7 to 8.0 is big, but always recomended. The discussion,as here is, always the same i write this Queries and . the behaviour for now is deteminuistic, mysql goes from To to bottom for every column and every row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function for this:

```
SELECT c.id, AES_DECRYPT(c.name, 'co1') as name, AES_DECRYPT(c.phone, 'co3') as phone, c.islive, r.rating
FROM company c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.cid ORDER BY r.thedate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM creditrating r
     ) r
     ON c.id = r.cid AND r.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have tested your version and it through up a few errors, I will play about with it to see if I can get your query to work some how

Comment: Just found out why I can not get this to work, after a little revision on how this works, it is because it is for version 8+ where as the database the server is on is 5.6